# How to restrict user access to some data

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, jasper-reports, business-intelligence

have one question regarding report builder services and BI platforms.
We have multytenant database mongoDB, where we store all our users data, user's orders, user's transactions.

I want each user be able to build their own report (thinking about to use one of these: CrystalReports, JasperSoft, ReportServer).

But the issue is- when user will have access to database (via CrystalReports for ex.), he can easily generate report with other users Orders or transaction data.
What is best practices to provide data (from one database) for users which will use report building tool?

Comment: BI tools such as Crystal Reports typically rely on the database management system to handle security and user authentication.  You may have more success getting the help you need by adding a tag for MongoDB and editing the question to indicate a need for help with setting up security for your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users should use some UI that operates with intermediate semantic model (dimensions, measures, filtering parameters). They should not have direct access to database and write an SQL - only exception is possible if you have separate DB for each customer.

Right solution highly depends on the purpose why users create their own reports. If primary goal is business intelligence you may offer your users some kind of pivot tables / pivot charts builder.